# Jquery mouseenter

Tags: jquery, html

I have just started to use jquery-1.8.3 rather than jquery-1.6.4 and the following code is no longer working. Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('#rico').mouseenter(function () {
        jQuery('.favourite-brands-infobox').hide();
        jQuery('#rico-info').show();
    });
    jQuery('#sirdar').mouseenter(function () {
        jQuery('.favourite-brands-infobox').hide();
        jQuery('#sirdar-info').show();
    });
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Theres nothing about your example that would cause an issue. My guess is the problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: please attach the `HTML` part also

Comment: Where do you have this code located?  In the markup or some other javascript?  Because as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned there shouldn't be an issue.  The only way I couldn't get it to work is if placed it in another `$(window).load(function(){//your code});`

Comment: This should maybe be moved over to [http://codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: tried changing .mouseenter(function () ... to .on("mouseenter", function () ...

Comment: Here is the HTML [FULL PAGE]http://hcscrafts.co.uk

Comment: which part of the page contains `#rico` and `#sirdar` elements

Answer (score -2):

try replacing

```
.mouseenter(function () ...
```

with

```
.on("mouseenter", function () ...
```

Comment: OK, now from this perspective I'm even more puzzled about downvotes. What I suggested here is actually now highly recommended, and the event aliases from the first approach is deprecated since jQuery 3.3